# Sorting months in R

Tags: r, date

I want to sort month names. When I use the `strptime` function it returns an error as the attribute values only contains month names. When I use the `sort` function, the months are sorted alphabetically.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

You could always convert your data to a factor. For example, suppose we have

```
x = c("January", "February", "March", "January")
```

then to convert to a factor, we have:

```
x_fac = factor(x, levels = month.name)
```

which on sorting gives:

```
R> sort(x_fac)
[1] January  January  February March   
12 Levels: January February March April May June July August ... December
```

Comment: Constants `month.name` and `month.abb` are useful in this regard so you don't need to type out the month names etc. Only useful for English month names and abbreviations though.

Comment: also, be careful with "Feburary" -- you're unlikely (I hope) to find it in the real data.  Maybe that was part of the reason for @GavinSimpson's suggestion

Comment: Thanks @GavinSimpson I didn't know about `month.name`

Answer (score 5):

This is crude but if you wanted to make a function to sort or order rows by a month this would work:

```
sort.month <- function(x, dataframe = NULL){
    y <- data.frame(m1 = month.name, m2 = month.abb, n = 1:12)
    z <- if(max(nchar(x)) == 3) match(x, y[, 'm2']) else match(x, y[, 'm1'])
    x <- if(is.null(dataframe)) x else dataframe
    h <- data.frame(z, x)
    h[order(z), ][, -1]
}

#examples
x <- sample(month.name, 20, r=T)
a<-data.frame(y= x, k =1:20, w=letters[1:20])
sort.month(a$y, a)
sort.month(a$y)
```

Comment: I use this type of sorting a lot inside the custom functions I create - so I prefer this approach over the minimalist or standard approach posted by @csgillespie (i.e. my vote goes here).

Comment: @SilSur at first I rejected the edit you suggested, but after considering more your suggestion was safe to assume internally.  I manually edited the post to match your suggested edits as it was too late once I rejected it.

Comment: ...so no brownie points for my edit?

Comment: Sorry no :-(  I am the worst.  I got this new power to approve edits and screwed it up my very first time.  With great power comes great responsibility.