# Can't get months in chronological order with facet_wrap

Tags: r, ggplot2, facet-wrap

```
weekend_trips %>%
  group_by(hour_of_day, member_casual, month) %>%
  summarise(number_of_rides = n()/2) %>%
  mutate(month = factor(month.name[as.numeric(month)]), levels = month.name) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = hour_of_day, y = number_of_rides, fill = member_casual)) + 
  geom_col(position = "dodge") +
  facet_wrap(~month)
```

This code gives me this: [Graphs in alphabetical order](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9J9N7.png)

If I don't cast month as.numberic, month becomes NA.

Edit: I figured it out.

```
weekend_trips$month <- month.name[as.numeric(weekend_trips$month)]

weekend_trips %>%
  group_by(hour_of_day, member_casual, month) %>%
  summarise(number_of_rides = n()/2) %>%
  mutate(month = factor(month, levels = month.name)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = hour_of_day, y = number_of_rides, fill = member_casual)) + 
  geom_col(position = "dodge") +
  facet_wrap (~month)
```

I would appreciate someone telling me why I couldn't burden mutate() so much.

Comment: You would need to specify `levels=c("January", "February", ...)`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9769609/sorting-months-in-r

Comment: try : `mutate(month = factor(month.name[as.numeric(month)]), levels = month.name, orderd = TRUE) `